# Select a portion of an image and retrieve its coordinates with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, coordinates

I need a way for user to select the portion of an image either by resizing transparent rectangle or by clicking and dragging the selection area (as it's done in desktop OS), both would work for me. Then i need to retrieve the coordinates of the selected area with jQuery.

Please recommend samples or tuts (if there are any), methods or API documentations sections that could help.

Comment: jCrop do something similar so you might check that code https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/blob/master/js/jquery.Jcrop.js

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [Jcrop](https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop) and it's demos.

```
<!-- This is the image we're attaching Jcrop to -->
<img src="demo_files/pool.jpg" id="target" alt="Flowers" />
```

And the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){

  $('#target').Jcrop({
    onChange:   showCoords,
    onSelect:   showCoords
  });

});

// Simple event handler, called from onChange and onSelect
// event handlers to show an alert, as per the Jcrop 
// invocation above

function showCoords(c)
{
  alert('x='+ c.x +' y='+ c.y +' x2='+ c.x2 +' y2='+ c.y2)
  alert('w='+c.w +' h='+ c.h)
};

</script>
```

Comment: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler This is exatly what i needed, thanks!

Comment: Fabulous solution been searching for ages. Thanks.

Comment: can we use these coords for <area> ?

Comment: Can we select area with pen tool

Answer (score 3):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Processs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/css/jquery.Jcrop.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYYqo.jpg" alt="" id="image">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#image').Jcrop({
                    onSelect: function(c){
                        console.log(c);

                        console.log(c.x);
                        console.log(c.y);
                        console.log(c.w);
                        console.log(c.h);
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>    
    </html>
```

Comment: Nice one, I have been searching fro something like this for long. Thank you!