# Getting image coordinates of mouse movement

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I am clicking (mouse down) at some position (say x1, y1) on an image and the moving the mouse and releasing mouse (mouse up) at some other location (x2, y2) within the image.

I need to capture these starting and ending coordinates.

I tried with mouseup and mousedown event but it's not working. When I do the mousedown at destination it does not return anything.

```
var startX, startY;
var endX, endY;
if (!document.all)
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
document.onmouseup = endPos;

if (!document.all)
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown = startPos;

function startPos (event)
{
   startX = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX - img1.offsetLeft;
   startY = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY - img1.offsetTop;
}

function endPos (event)
{
   endX = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX - img1.offsetLeft;
   endY = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY - img1.offsetTop;
}
```

Comment: Please, show some code first.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: without code all answers are biased

Comment: No alert, no console.log? ... Describe "Show anything" please.

Comment: It's resolved by following

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506041/javascript-events-mouseup-not-firing-after-mousemove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jCrop](https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop) to get this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){

  $('#target').Jcrop({
    onChange:   showCoords,
    onSelect:   showCoords
  });

});

// Simple event handler, called from onChange and onSelect
// event handlers, as per the Jcrop invocation above
function showCoords(c)
{
  alert('x='+ c.x +' y='+ c.y +' x2='+ c.x2 +' y2='+ x.y2)
  alert('w='+c.w +' h='+ c.h)
};

</script>
```

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822371/select-a-portion-of-an-image-and-retrieve-its-coordinates-with-jquery)

Comment: any other way in simple javascript?

Comment: sorry i dont know.But it is better way to do this

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this will be what you want.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('result');
var startPosX = 0, startPosY = 0, endPosX = 0, endPosY = 0;
function startPos(e) {
   var eve = (e) ? e : window.event;
   var x = (eve.layerX) ? eve.layerX : eve.offsetX;
   var y = (eve.layerX) ? eve.layerY : eve.offsetY;
   startPosX = x, startPosY = y;
}
function endPos(e) {
   var eve = (e) ? e : window.event;
   var x = (eve.layerX) ? eve.layerX : eve.offsetX;
   var y = (eve.layerX) ? eve.layerY : eve.offsetY;
   endPosX = x, endPosY = y;
elem.innerHTML = 'startPos(X)= ' + startPosX + ' | startPos(Y)= ' + startPosY + '<br/> endPos(X)= ' + endPosX + ' | endPos(Y)= ' + endPosY;
}

document.onmousedown = startPos;
document.onmouseup = endPos;
```

[**Online demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pfwPC/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do something like this:

```
$(function(){

var positionRequester = function(element, callback){
        var startX = 0,
            startY = 0,
            endX = 0,
            endY = 0;

       $(element).unbind("mousedown").on("mousedown",function(e){
            console.log(e);
       });

        $(element).unbind("mouseup").on("mouseup",function(e){
            callback(startX,startY,endX,endY);
        });

};

positionRequester("div",function(startX,startY,endX,endY){
    console.log(startX,startY,endX,endY);
})
```

});

In "mousedown" you could capture thge start point, in "mouseup" you could call the callback..

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     $("div").html("CLICK ME");
     $(".box").bind("mousemove",function(e ){
         $("div").html("X="+e.pageX +"px"+'<br/>' +"Y ="+e.pageY +"px");
     });
});
```