# How to show very specific potion of the image

Tags: javascript, css, image, reactjs, react-native

[image]

From the image above, I want to show only the portion (inside of white border) of image. I'm using React Native but I think this can be either Javascript, CSS, or React Native problem.

The example white border location information can be given: If the white square is located in (200, 200) at left top coordinate with 100 wide square, the data for white square is `left:200, top:200, thumbSize:100`.

Example Code:

```
return (
  <Image
    source={require('../../path/img.jpg')}
    ??
    style={{??}}
  />
);
```

Can I show very specific portion of the image with given data? (left, top, thumbSize)

Thanks!!

**UPDATE** Expected output is 100 by 100 square located at (200, 200).

Comment: You can get help from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822371/select-a-portion-of-an-image-and-retrieve-its-coordinates-with-jquery

Comment: Um it's little different. Rather than selecting its portion, I want to show 100 by 100 square instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Tested on Chromium 62***

```
img {
 position: absolute;
 clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
 }
```

using clip property in CSS you can clip it.
show any part you want to show.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm working on React Native. I'm looking for answer for React Native CSS. But I can develop your solution to mine :)